# Choice.IMPLICIT and Choice.EXCLUSIVE in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, midp, illegalargumentexception, lcdui

Why we can't use `Choice.IMPLICIT` with in a Form while we can use `Choice.EXCLUSIVE`. When I use `Choice.IMPLICIT`, it gives me a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

```
 ChoiceGroup msgChoGrp = new ChoiceGroup("", Choice.EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use (mis-use) the MIDP 2 API, `IAE` is the correct behavior because it is exactly what API javadocs require for [ChoiceGroup(String label, int choiceType)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ChoiceGroup.html#ChoiceGroup%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if choiceType is not one of EXCLUSIVE, MULTIPLE, or POPUP

By the way if all you want is to get rid of radio-buttons and check-boxes, try `POPUP` kind of ChoiceGroup. If you need to get even closer to implicit List, if you need this really badly, consider `CustomItem` - though this might require thorough study of API to implement correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can use Choice Implicit with List just check [Choice Implicit example with List](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=731)
Thanks

Comment: Yes that's true. But that is not my point. My point is we have a Form. With in that form we are calling ChoiceGroup.              <pre>Form frm = new Form("my form");
ChoiceGroup cg = new ChoiceGroup("", Choice.IMPLICIT);
frm.append(cg);      </pre>                                               We can't do this. Why is that? But we can do it with (Choice.EXCLUSIVE)

Answer (score 1):

Implicit is for list

and exclusive for choice group

may be you use form so implicit cant be applied :D